# Restkit - Cannot set the Preferred Output Date Formatter with RKDotNetDateFormatter

Tags: ios, web-services, restkit, date-parsing

I follow the [Restkit wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Configuring-Date-and-Time-Mapping) and succeed to parse ASP.NET date to NSDate. But I cannot set the default output, whatever I do, it still outputs as the following format: "2010-01-27 00:00:00 +0000".

Here is what I try

```
    [RKObjectMapping addDefaultDateFormatter:[RKDotNetDateFormatter dotNetDateFormatter]];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    // Set it Globally
    [RKObjectMapping setPreferredDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
```

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and tracked it down to an initialize() method in RKObjectMapping.m where it inserts an RKISO8601DateFormatter at the top of the list. Once I commented out that line my custom date formatter was used.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/ObjectMapping/RKObjectMapping.m#L140

I've opened a defect with RestKit but I could just be missing something.
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1753

Hope this helps you.